# Plotly: show every color of custom colorscale on colorbar

Tags: python, plotly, colorbar

I have a custom colorscale for my colorbar with 17 different colors, and my data is 29x29 matrix with values in range of 0-16. I would like my colorbar to show all 17 colors for every value in the matrix, then the ticks on the colorbar would be 0,1,2,3...16 and every tick would be associated with one color. As it is, my colorbar have every other tick shown, and about half of the colors. How can I change that and show every color and tick on my colorbar?

This is my test data:

```
    import numpy as np
    import plotly.graph_objects as go

    #custom colorscale
    colors=[(0.0,'#170d33' ), (0.0588, '#170d33'),
            (0.0588, '#2f4b7c'),(0.118,'#2f4b7c'),
            (0.118,'#2f4b7c'),(0.177,'#2f4b7c'),
            (0.177,'#665191'),(0.236,'#665191'),
            (0.236,'#875296'),(0.295,'#875296'),
            (0.295,'#a05195'),(0.354,'#a05195'),
            (0.354,'#d45087'),(0.413,'#d45087'),
            (0.413,'#f95d6a'),(0.471,'#f95d6a'),
            (0.471,'#ff7c43'),(0.53,'#ff7c43'),
            (0.53,'#ffa600'),(0.589,'#ffa600'),
            (0.589,'#ffc332'),(0.648,'#ffc332'),
            (0.648,'#fff629'),(0.707,'#fff629'),
            (0.707,'#f7ffbd'),(0.765,'#f7ffbd'),
            (0.765,'#d2ffbd'),(0.824,'#d2ffbd'),
            (0.824,'#a2ffc9'),(0.883,'#a2ffc9'),
            (0.883,'#85ffd4'),(0.942,'#85ffd4'),
            (0.942,'#1cfff0'),(1.0,'#1cfff0')]

    #random matrix illustrating my data
    mx=np.random.uniform(low=0., high=16, size=(29,29) )  

    fig=go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Contour(z=mx, coloraxis='coloraxis'))
    fig.update_layout(height=800, width=1000, coloraxis=dict(colorscale=colors), 
                        showlegend=False, font=dict(size=24), font_family='Open Sans')
    fig.show()
```

[image: Test contour]

EDIT: I thought that if I provide enough colors (same number or more then number of values) the colorbar would automatically configure colorbar like that - one color-one tick. Not really, it seams.
Here is another test with matrix values 0-10, and colorbar shows what I want. Maybe I should provide even more colors, if there is no explicit way to configure color-value of colorbar?

[image]

Comment: I dont see any colors in the graph that are not in the color legend so my hypothesis is that its not an issue with plotly but maybe more a problem with your data

Comment: @elizevin Could you share some specifics on `"show every color"`? It sounds like you're aiming to designate *one specific color* to *one specifi number*. And that also sounds to be of a *categorical* nature. And not numcerical. Or continuous. Which a `go.Contour` plot *is*.

Comment: @elizevin If my above assumptions are wrong, there migh be ways to display `"colors for every value in the matrix"` on *continuous* axes.

Comment: @vestland That approach  would be useful for this specific problem, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your best option for showing *every* color is:

```
fig.data[0].contours.coloring = 'heatmap'
```

[image]

#### Code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data =
    go.Contour(
        z=[[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
           [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
           [2.5, 3.125, 5., 8.125, 12.5],
           [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
           [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]]
    ))

fig.data[0].contours.coloring = 'heatmap'

fig.show()
```

Comment: hm, this isn't quite what I had in mind. My ideal solution would be discrete colors on colorbar with all of the colors on it and tick associated with every color in such way that one tick is corresponding with one color. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: @elizevin No, not to my knowledge.